# VS tools for apache cordova

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I installed VS 2015 community with the ISO installer. Since then I have been trying to install apache cordova tools from the programs-change-modify method in my pc's control panel but to no avail. It only acquires and applies the windows sdk and c++ but not the html/javascript(apache cordova).
I even tried installing the dependencies manually but still no success. 
Please what is the easiest way to get this done since I am new to visual studio and coding in general.

Thanks 
Euston

Comment: what do you mean by "no avail"? And could you please post a screenshot of your installation feature-selection panel?

Comment: I have completed the installation. Thank you.